# PrettyTable is not printing table correctly in tkinter (python GUI)

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, prettytable

I am trying to print table via `PrettyTable` library in python in my `ScrolledText` tkinter widget.
here is the function snippet:

```
global Scrolledtext1
Scrolledtext1 = ScrolledText(top, state="disable")

def display_output(self,output_message):
        myTable = PrettyTable()
        
        for list_item in output_message:
            myTable.add_row(list_item)
            
        print(myTable)
        
        Scrolledtext1.config(state="normal")        # changing text box's state so that we can edit it
        Scrolledtext1.delete("1.0", "end")          # deletes previous contents
        Scrolledtext1.insert(1.0,myTable)           # showing output message
        Scrolledtext1.config(state="disable")       # disabling text box's state so that user cannot change it's content
```

I am inserting myTable in second last line in above code (in *insert* method).
this is **printing table correctly** in `console` via print statement but it is **not printing correctly** in `ScrolledText` .
This is screenshot of this table which is inserted in `ScrolledText` in tkinter:

GUI output image

[image]

console output image

[image]

Please suggest me something so that i can print table correctly in `ScrolledText`.

Comment: You need to use a fixed width font.

Comment: Pick one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces) fonts. They are monospaced like in your console. Make sure that font is available on your computer. You can use the `font` parameter in your 
widget initialisation `ScrolledText(top, state="disable")` like this: `ScrolledText(top, state="disable", font=(<fontname as a string>, <fontsize as an int>))`

Comment: @BryanOakley How to use fixed width font? Could you please elaborate with an example?